# Why can't AngularJS app consume REST service on different server?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-boot, cors

**How do I call a Spring Boot REST api from an AngularJS app running on a different server?**  Specifically, how do I modify the code below to accomplish this?

I am learning Spring Boot using [the tutorial at this link](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/).  Part one and Part two of the app run perfectly.  In [part three of the tutorial (which is at this link)](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_the_resource_server_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_iii), we move the REST api to a different resource server, which is prototyped as `localhost:9000`.

The tutorial makes the resource server app in groovy, but I am trying to modify it to be in Java.

I am able to access the web service at `localhost:9000` when I define `/home/username/workspacename/resource/src/main/java/com/example/ResourceApplication.java` as shown below.

However, the AngularJS app running on `localhost:8080` cannot access the web service from `localhost:9000`.  When I then add `CorsFilter.java` as shown below and restart the service with `kill $(lsof -t -i:9000)` and `mvn spring-boot:run`, I can no longer view the data at `localhost:9000`, and I also am still not able access the web service from the app in `localhost:8080`.

I did not make any other changes to the code, and I stopped at the point in the tutorial where `CorsFilter.java` is created and the app is restarted.  **So how do I change the code below to get the web service from `localhost:9000` to be accessible from the gui app at `localhost:8080`?**

The code for the two changed classes in the resource server is as follows:

`/home/username/workspacename/resource/src/main/java/com/example/ResourceApplication.java` is:

```
package com.example;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class ResourceApplication {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public Map<String,Object> home() {
        Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        model.put("content", "Hello World");
        return model;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ResourceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

`/home/username/workspacename/resource/src/main/java/com/example/CorsFilter.java` is:

```
package com.example;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
class CorsFilter implements Filter {

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
      try {chain.doFilter(req, res);} 
      catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();} 
      catch (ServletException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    } 
    else {    }
  }

  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

  public void destroy() {}

}
```

And the code for the `hello.js` file **in the GUI app at `localhost:8080`** is:

```
angular.module('hello', [ 'ngRoute' ])
.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'home.html',
        controller : 'home'
    }).when('/login', {
        templateUrl : 'login.html',
        controller : 'navigation'
    }).otherwise('/');

  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

})
.controller('home', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://localhost:9000/').success(function(data) {
    $scope.greeting = data;
  })
})
.controller('navigation', 

          function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location) {

      var authenticate = function(credentials, callback) {

        var headers = credentials ? {authorization : "Basic "
            + btoa(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)
        } : {};

        $http.get('user', {headers : headers}).success(function(data) {
          if (data.name) {
            $rootScope.authenticated = true;
          } else {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
          }
          callback && callback();
        }).error(function() {
          $rootScope.authenticated = false;
          callback && callback();
        });

      }

      authenticate();
      $scope.credentials = {};
      $scope.login = function() {
          authenticate($scope.credentials, function() {
            if ($rootScope.authenticated) {
              $location.path("/");
              $scope.error = false;    
            } else {
              $location.path("/login");
              $scope.error = true;
            }
          });
      };

      $scope.logout = function() {
          $http.post('logout', {}).success(function() {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            $location.path("/");
          }).error(function(data) {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
          });
        }

    });
```

---

**ONGOING RESEARCH:**

---

As per @meriton's request, I opened the developer tools in firefox and then requested `localhost:8080`.  When I zoomed in to Network tab for the response headers for the GET request for the call to `localhost:9000` embedded in the `localhost:8080` request, I got the following request headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 08 Dec 2015 00:41:01 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
access-control-allow-origin: *
```

And the following request headers were also shown in the `Network` tab:

```
Host: localhost:9000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: What do you mean by " I can no longer view the data at localhost:9000"? Do you get an error? If so, what error?

Comment: @meriton I just get a white blank page. No error in the browser.  I will use the developer tools to see what shows up in those logs.  Where else should I look?

Comment: The developer tools. Specifically, the javascript console, and if the server response is anomalous, the network tab. If there is no error on the javascript console, and the response looks valid, you'll have to debug the code that sends the rest request and processes the response.

Comment: @meriton I just called `localhost:9000` in firefox with the developer tools open.  The debugger tab says `no sources`, and  `no stack frames`.  And when I call it again from the network tab, the log lists a call to `/` with 0kb in response.

Comment: What is the HTTP status and the headers of the response? That said, this sounds like your server is misbehaving.

Comment: @meriton When I call `localhost:8080` with the console tab open, the result is:  `no element found localhost:9000:1:1`  The network tab for the `localhost:8080` request also shows a `GET` request to `localhost:9000` with 0kb response.

Comment: @meriton I added the request headers and the response headers to the end of my OP.  Does this provide useful information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Filter is an interceptor for servlet that can choose to handle the request itself, or pass it one to the next filter or servlet in the filter chain using `chain.doFilter(req, res)`. Your filter only passes on option requests, all other requests (such as a GET request) are neither passed on or otherwise responded to:

```
if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
  try {chain.doFilter(req, res);} 
  catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();} 
  catch (ServletException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
} 
else {    }
```

as the response is never written to, it remains empty, which explains the 0KB response the server replies with.

As for fixing this, you should either transscribe the example code correctly, i.e. the tutorial code

```
if (request.getMethod()!='OPTIONS') {
  chain.doFilter(req, res)
} else {
}
```

should become

```
if (!request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
  chain.doFilter(req, res)
} else {
}
```

(note the negation!) or better yet

```
if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
    // preflight request
} else {
    chain.doFilter(req, res)
}
```

However, it may be easier to use the [CORS-Support provided by Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) rather than implementing it yourself.

Comment: Thank you.  You caught my error.  I turned `!=` into `string.equals`.  It should be `!string.equals`.

Comment: I have another question further down in the same tutorial.  Are you willing to please comment on it also?  Here is the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235409/why-cant-spring-boot-angularjs-gateway-app-read-from-ui-app