# why can't spring boot angularjs gateway app read from ui app?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am learning about spring's scalability features using the tutorial at the following link.  Specifically, [part 6 of the tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_multiple_ui_applications_and_a_gateway_single_page_application_with_spring_and_angular_js_part_vi) uses a gateway app to regulate access to apps running on other servers.

I have followed the steps below precisely, but when I start all three apps and then type in `localhost:8080/ui` into my web browser, all I get is the word "Greeting" with no id or hello world, and with no css.

When I open the developer tools for the request in Firefox, I see that the GET requests for css and js resources are getting 404 errors pointing to urls like `http://localhost:8080/js/hello.js` **instead of** pointing to `http://localhost:8080/ui/js/hello.js`, as [the test section of the tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_up_and_running) suggests.  **How can I change this so that the greeting displays in the browser?**

Here is what I have done step by step, following the tutorial's step six by first recreating the `ui` starting point from part one and the `resource` starting point from part three:

---

**Create the UI sample starter app**

---

```
# mkdir ui 
# chmod -R 777 ui
# cd ui
# curl https://start.spring.io/starter.tgz -d style=web -d style=security -d name=ui | tar -xzvf -
```

Eclipse > File > Import > Existing Maven Projects > Navigate to ui folder > Finish

Create `index.html` in `src/main/resources/static` and add the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello AngularJS</title>
<link href="css/angular-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
</style>
</head>

<body ng-app="hello">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Greeting</h1>
    <div ng-controller="home" ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">
      <p>The ID is {{greeting.id}}</p>
      <p>The content is {{greeting.content}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/angular-bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/hello.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Add the following lines to `src/main/resources/application.properties`:

```
security.user.password=some.password
server.port: 8081
security.sessions: NEVER  // The "security.sessions" setting means that Spring Security will accept cookies as authentication tokens but won’t create them unless they already exist.
```

Add the following to `pom.xml` in order to download and integrate angular and bootstrap etc using wro4j:

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
    <resource>
      <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources</directory>
    </resource>
  </resources>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <!-- Serves *only* to filter the wro.xml so it can get an absolute
            path for the project -->
          <id>copy-resources</id>
          <phase>validate</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/wro</outputDirectory>
            <resources>
              <resource>
                <directory>src/main/wro</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
              </resource>
            </resources>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.6</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>generate-resources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <wroManagerFactory>ro.isdc.wro.maven.plugin.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory</wroManagerFactory>
        <cssDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/static/css</cssDestinationFolder>
        <jsDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/static/js</jsDestinationFolder>
        <wroFile>${project.build.directory}/wro/wro.xml</wroFile>
        <extraConfigFile>${basedir}/src/main/wro/wro.properties</extraConfigFile>
        <contextFolder>${basedir}/src/main/wro</contextFolder>
      </configuration>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
          <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
          <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
          <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Eclipse > File > New > Source Folder > (create src/main/wro)

Add the following to `src/main/wro/wro.properties` (will compile css from less and minify javascript):

```
preProcessors=lessCssImport
postProcessors=less4j,jsMin
```

Add the following to `src/main/wro/wro.xml` (declares a single group angular-bootstrap with references to css, js, and main.less):

```
<groups xmlns="http://www.isdc.ro/wro">
  <group name="angular-bootstrap">
  <css>webjar:bootstrap/3.2.0/less/bootstrap.less</css>
    <css>file:${project.basedir}/src/main/wro/main.less</css>
    <js>webjar:jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js</js>
    <js>webjar:angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js</js>
  </group>
</groups>
```

Create `src/main/wro/main.less` and leave it empty for now.  `main.less` can be used to customize bootstrap defaults.

Create `src/main/resources/static/js/hello.js` and add the following:

```
angular.module('hello', [])
  .controller('home', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/resource/').success(function(data) {
    $scope.greeting = data;
  })
});
```

Change `com.example.UiApplication.java` to:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.EnableRedisHttpSession;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class UiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

// now add the following to the ui app's pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

---

**Create separate resource server**

---

// navigate to root of workspace

```
# cd /home/username/someworkspace
# mkdir resource 
# chmod -R 777 resource 
# cd resource
# curl https://start.spring.io/starter.tgz -d style=web -d name=resource -d language=java | tar -xzvf -
```

Eclipse > Import > Existing Maven Project (navigate to resource folder just created)

// add the following to `pom.xml` in the `resource` app:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

// change `com.example.ResourceApplication.java` to the following:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.EnableRedisHttpSession;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class ResourceApplication {

  @RequestMapping("/resource")
  public Map<String,Object> home() {
    Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    model.put("content", "Hello World");
    return model;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ResourceApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

// Add the following to `src/main/resources/application.properties`:

```
server.port: 9000
security.sessions: NEVER
```

---

**create the gateway app**

---

navigate terminal to root of workspace, then

```
# cd /home/username/someworkspace
# mkdir gateway 
# chmod -R 777 gateway 
# cd gateway
# curl https://cloud-start.spring.io/starter.tgz -d style=web -d style=security -d style=cloud-zuul -d name=gateway -d style=redis | tar -xzvf -
```

Eclipse > File > Import > Existing Maven Project > (navigate to the gateway directory)

// change `GatewayApplication.java` to:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;
import org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.EnableRedisHttpSession;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRedisHttpSession
@EnableZuulProxy
public class GatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

// change `src/main/resources/application.properties` to:

```
zuul.routes.ui.url: http://localhost:8081
zuul.routes.resource.url: http://localhost:9000
security.user.password: password
security.sessions: ALWAYS
```

.
**Start and test the apps:**

```
# cd /home/username/someworkspace/ui
# mvn spring-boot:run
```

Then open a second terminal and type

```
# cd /home/username/someworkspace/resource
# mvn spring-boot:run
```

Then open a third terminal and type:

```
# cd /home/username/someworkspace/gateway
# mvn spring-boot: run
```

// test the app by putting localhost:8080/ui in the browser

Note that only the word "Greeting" shows up in the browser at `localhost:8080/ui`, and that there is no id and no content. Also, the firefox developer tools show 404 errors for resources like `http://localhost:8080/js/hello.js` which **should instead be** `http://localhost:8080/ui/js/hello.js`

However, when I type `localhost:8081` in the browser, I get the css-styled "Greeting" followed by "The ID is" and "The content is", but no dynamic content from the resource server.  The firefox developer tools for the `localhost:8081` request give a 404 for `http://localhost:8081/resource/`.

Note that, to test any changes to the above, you just type control C in the appropriate console, then type `kill $(lsof -t -i:8080)` or 8081 or 9000, and then `mvn spring-boot:run`

**So what changes to I make to the code above to get the id and greeting to load through the gateway?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an issue in your html page. You should make sure that links are correct. What Zuul in essence does is mapping urls from the gateway to the backend. To make your example work you have to either change the url in your angular app to `/resource/resource` or change the controller in the resource app to `/`. Also make sure that all of your apps have spring-boot-starter-security as a dependency to allow sharing of the sec context. Or disable security completely to debug your issue first.

Comment: The code above clearly states `src=js/...` and NOT `src=/js/...`.  Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Well yes but your post also reads like you copied the howto. Just wanted to be sure. Cause when your html loads correctly opening /ui/ and trying to load /js/ it looks to me like absolute linking.

Comment: I took careful notes of each step as I went along, then I posted my actual steps in the OP so that anyone can reproduce the steps that I took.  Do you have specific suggestions based on the actual steps that I documented in my OP?

Comment: Changing it to `ui/js/...` gets the css, id label, and greeting label to load.  But there is still no data being loaded from the resource server.  Also, this seems like a jerry-rig solution.  How do we set the application context for the include files so that the code does not break when we move the url of the ui app to a different name?

Comment: Well you can easily set the context via `server.contextPath` in the properties or while starting the server as env var or argument. This is also something which I'd suggest to try.

Comment: Do you mean in `hello.js`?  If so, what specific syntax?

Comment: No, when you start the ui server.

Comment: So what specific line of code do I add to `ui/src/main/resources/application.properties` to accomplish what you suggest?

Comment: `server.contextPath=ui`

Comment: `server.contextPath=ui` gives a compilation error stating that context paths must begin with `/`, and then `server.contextPath=/ui` compiles but gives a 404 error when `localhost:8080/ui` is called from the browser.

Comment: Did you also changed the route in Zuul to let /ui point to localhost:8081/ui?

Comment: Changing the `Zuul route` now enables the `css` and `js` to be loaded when I type `localhost:8080/ui`, but the call to the `resource` server still gives a 404, so there are no values for the id or message.

Comment: Your changed caused the call to the resource server to return a 404 error when it used to return a 500.  However, when I type `localhost:9000` in the browser, I still get a 500 error.

Comment: Well, `localhost:9000` should actually return a 500 cause the only mapping of this is `/resource`. But for me it looks like there is somewhere a bigger issue. Do you get the Json response when you open `localhost:9000/resource`? Could you share your setup somewhere on github or bitbucket?

Comment: Well and actually comparing your code with the linked tutorial shows 2 significant differences. The resource server exposes the UUID under `/` and not `/resource` as you have it. And I'm also actually not sure if how you configured the Zuul routes with properties is the same as doing so with yaml like in the tutorial, cause with yaml you can comfigure ant-like matching instead of just a name.

Comment: Thank you.  Since the three small sample test apps are in a test eclipse workspace, I zipped up the entire eclipse workspace using the command `tar zcvf workspace_scalable.tar.gz workspace_scalable/`,  The three small test apps are the ONLY contents of the workspace.  You can download the workspace, unzip it, and look at the app code using the link at this file sharing site: https://jumpshare.com/v/XJ2CfqfwLSClbuB8Cb1W

Comment: When I change `/resource` to `/` in `ResourceApplication.java`, the resulting 404 record in Firefox says that the call was made to `http://localhost:8081/resource/`.  But note that the `resource` url pattern is defined in the `gateway` app's `appliction.properties`.  I am just learning this, so I am not sure how that impacts things.

Comment: So for me it is working doing the changes proposed. So what I did is changing the mapping of `/resource` to `/`. Calling then `http://localhost:8080/resource/` will be routed internally to `http://localhost:9000/` and being answered correctly. The only thing which was missing is `spring-boot-starter-security` in your resource app. Actually if you would have read the logs it tells you this cause you see that an `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl` is thrown.

Comment: Please find working solution here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tp6b7tera6exl59/workspace_scalable.zip?dl=0

Comment: I downloaded the zip file from your link, unzipped it, then created a fresh empty eclipse workspace and imported the three small test apps into the new empty workspace.  I then navigated to the root of each small app and typed `mvn spring-boot:run`, but got just the word `Greeting` with no `css` or `js` when I typed `localhost:8080/ui` in browser, so I added `server.contextPath=/ui` and changed the `Zuul route` as in preceding comments.  Now the `css` and `js` load with `localhost:8080/ui`, but the embedded GET `localhost:8081/resource/` still gives a 404 for that there is no message or id.

Comment: The same setup was working for me. What exceptions you are getting?

Comment: It works at `localhost:8080/ui` now, but not at `localhost:8081/ui`.  This is acceptable because it will only be called from `localhost:8080/ui`.  But are you willing to show in your answer above what changes you made to make this happen?  That would make it reproducable and help people actually learn from this instead of just fixing a bug in one situation.  Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to develop repeatable steps for creating cloud-based apps to run on this architecture.  I would really appreciate it if you could state explicitly what you did to make it work instead of just posting a zip.  As it stands, someone would have to download your zip and take it on faith to make it work instead of being able to understand how to build it from scratch oneself.

Comment: Updated the answer solving your issue. Please accept.

Comment: I accepted.  But does your answer really list everything that you changed? If so, I will test creating from scratch, this time including your changes, in order to make sure that it works in a recreate-able way.

Comment: Yes! That are all the changes I did. I even reverted back the `server.contextPath` setting cause it was not necessary at all. And the 500 issue with resource server was rather easy to spot cause the service was complaining about a missing SecurityContext. Might be that you also changed something along our discussion but I only did the above.